# Network time

Tags: android, сеть

Добрый день! Необходимо получить актуальное UTC время в формате 1 359 309 564
для этого нашел сервис который предоставляет мне информацию! Но хотелось бы получить время от оператора, нашел такой код:

```
LocationManager locMan = (LocationManager) activity.getSystemService(activity.LOCATION_SERVICE);
long networkTS = locMan.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER).getTime();
```

Но `locMan.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)` возвращает null, мол нет кешированых данных о последней локации! можно ли как нибудь подсунуть ему локацию, что бы он мне вернул UTC время?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно определить время текущего местоположения, то запросите новую, установив обработчик LocationListener, тогда null возвращаться не будет при вызове getLastKnownLocation().
Ну или передайте координаты в объект Location с помощью setLongtitude/setLatitude и вызовите getTime(), но подозреваю, что время если и вернется, то некорректное.